# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on a ASRock with a BIOS that is set for gaming

Tags: system-installation

I just bought myself a new desktop which has an "ASRock H370 Pro4" motherboard. The computer was meant to be pre-install with Win.10 and is primary sold as a "Gamer Computer".

I stopped the installation of Windows by telling the seller that I used "Open Source" and Linux Ubuntu. The seller had no problem with this, of course, and sold then sent me the computer.

I then went on with the installation, which I have done 3 times now, with a pre-installed bootable USB stick/pen and also a burned DVD.

Is there a way to clean up this mess and be sure there is only one install that's being used?

Each time the installation goes fine, but when I start up the system after I am told to reboot, the system "freezes" showing a screen that says "_ _ _ (Div) Files and Blocks are being cleaned".
This screen is just like a basic terminal window.

I think the problem lies in the BIOS, but remember it has a setup for gamers and this is an environment that I don't know anything about. There should be a place to "tick" because of the legacy BIOS compatibility that allows legacy operating systems.

I have however, set the "Secure Boot" to disabled and then launching CSM is enabled.

Comment: Looks like it's fixing the filesystem, so nothing to do with BIOS/UEFI settings.  Did you ever let it finish?  It might take awhile, watch the disk activity light.

Comment: Thank`s Allot ubfan1 :-).  Last time I did this I forgot al about the activity light.

Comment: Think`s are now actually totally different. Just hear in front of me the "frozen screen" I was talking about has changed. There is now 24 hours waiting, now there is the proper terminal window and it`s a live and obviously working through the systems continence. & so again THANK`s TO ubfan1 and may he/her have the most perfect life a head of he/her  :-).

Comment: The "Screen" is stil hear and is now working on; "Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities". It has however been doing this for 2 days and some. How long does a operation like this actually last ???

Comment: That does seem very slow, but if it's making progress, I'd let it finish.  Check the directory /var/cache/apt/archives to see if the downloads are still happening.  Check with free to see if swap is being used. What's your download link speed?  Ever do a memory check and disk check with smartctl (from the smartmontools package)?